# Protractor assert each element of array is less than 500

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

I'm using Protractor for my tests, and want assert that each price of few products on page is less than 500. Using `element.all('.money')` I'm getting array like this `[ '$450', '$495', '$475' ]`. How do I assert that each element of my array is less than 500?
I'm trying something like this

```
var price = function() {
    $$('.money').getText().then(function(elements){
        var numbers = elements.map(x => x.replace('$',''))
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            expect(numbers[i]).toBeLessThan(500);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to  resolve your promise with `.then()`. After this, you can use `.toBeGreaterThan()` to assert that  each element is greater than `500`.

```
element.all(.money).then(function(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    expect(i).toBeGreaterThan(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: makes sense, but first I need to get text of all elements, then get rid of dollar signs for each element, and then make assrtion

Comment: You could always do that in the `.then()`, with something like `.replace(/\$/g, '')` to remove the dollar signs.

Comment: I wrote this: `var price = function() {
        $$('.money').getText().then(function(elements){
            var numbers = elements.map(x => x.replace('$',''))
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                expect(numbers[i]).toBeLessThan(500);
            }
        })
    }` and my test passes, but I don't understand how, I compare string with number, here is my array `[ '450', '495', '475' ]` and elements not a numbers